# react-image-uploader upload on submit button

Tags: reactjs

I found [this awesome react package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-images-uploader) for uploading multiple images.

The images get uploaded to the server once they are selected from the filesystem via the browse window. What I want is to start uploading them when I press a "submit" button. So I can only see their preview, but they are not actually sent unless the button is pressed. The reason is because I have other data that I want to be sent together with the images.

I am a beginner to React, can someone please point me if there is a way to achieve this? maybe extend the * ImagesUploader* class?

Comment: please provide your code

Comment: @YuriRamos I have no custom code. All I want is to somehow customize that package.

Comment: 1) Download the package from github 2) Study the code 3) Learn React 4) Modify it to your own needs

Comment: @Mikke Learning react has nothing to do with the way a npm package can be extended/modified. So I suggest you this: 1) go home 2) lock yourself in the basement 3) never go out again 4) everybody will be happier

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: After looking at the package you are using (and reading a bit of the code), it looks like you can't (easily) hook into the trigger for uploading - that is, not without forking the project, adding your own "pause" like mechanism, and see if he'd accept a PR.

He doesn't expose any hooks to manually start the upload, only callbacks for `onLoadStart()` and `onLoadEnd()`.

My initial thought was to somehow add a generator function in the `onLoadStart()` that pauses the upload until you call `next()` with your generator... but... this is not easily accomplished... sorry. I'll leave my original answer in case someone needs the info later.

Add your functions to the `onChange` event handler so that when the user selects a file it gets triggered. You add the on change to the `<input>` element.

```js
// example

class FileUploadComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      file: ''
    }
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this)
  }
  handleChange(e) {
    this.setState({file: e.target.files[0]})
    // do your other "pre-submitted" logic here
  }
  handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { file } = this.state
    // do something with the file
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type='file' onChange={this.handleChange}/>
        <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}></button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: The thing is that the existing handler for *onChange* does a lot of things. But it doesn't submit the images. * loadImages* does that. However, I also need to add a submit button and I don'tknow how to connect it to the componenet

Comment: I know how to do this but the thing is that I need to hook with the ImagesUploader, that comes with the package I mentioned not using react's builtin ones